# Unable to switch between adb usb to adb tcp mode successfully

Tags: android, networking, adb, android-networking

I have two device from which one supports adb over usb and another supports adb over ethernet(tcp) as it doesn't have wifi I need to connect it using ethernet for internet access. Whenever I need to switch between the two devices I need to restart the PC to connect with adb successfully which is quite irritating. I tried to switch between usb to tcp but failed so the solution currently I am having is restart the PC everytime. So, here I am looking for a better solution which will save me from restart my PC for switching between usb to tcp or vice-versa mode.

Now, the problem I am facing swiching between usb to tcp is as below

```
C:\Users\plalit>adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

C:\Users\plalit>adb connect 192.168.1.137
not implement

C:\Users\plalit>adb connect 192.168.1.137
not implement
```

Also, I tried adding port number

```
C:\Users\plalit>adb connect 192.168.1.137:5555
not implement
```

As you can see it say **"not implement"**, also if I try to kill adb and restart it then it give me a message as below

```
C:\Users\plalit>adb kill-server
* server not running *
```

So, I am able to connect the device via usb(one device) but not able to connect another device via tcp for that I need to restart my PC.

> Ways I had already tried,

- Restarting eclipse
- Killing adb.exe from Task Manager(but there is not process with adb.exe)
- Restarting adb from eclipse DDMS

Does anyone have a solution for this or has anyone faced this kind of issue/problem, anyways to resolved it.

Comment: make sure you followed this and you are having one healthy wireless network same used by your device and PC :- http://mehrvarz.github.io/android-debug-sans-usb/

Comment: When you run `adb tcpip 5555` which device is connected via USB?

Comment: yes, I tried with both connected it and tried with disconnecting it also!

Comment: Please make sure that _only_ the one you want to run adb tcpip connection is connected via USB. Also, can you check if you can ping the target?

Comment: yes I am tried all the ways, only one device is connected at a time!

Comment: After `adb kill-server` try `adb tcpip 5555` you will see this `* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *` and then `adb connect 192.168.1.137`

Answer (score 2):

There is an app for that:) It's called "Adb wireless" but you need root access on your "ethernet only" device.

In order to make those commands `adb tcpip 5555` and `adb connect <ip>:<port>` work over tcp I believe you need to connect your device via usb cable first, and only then you can enable the tcpip connection manually.

If your device is rooted you should be able to use a terminal emulator and start adb on it manualy see here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/3740005/1505341 also pretty the much same thing here:http://takeshikanemoto.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/adb-over-tcpip/

The "Adb wireless (no root)" apps on google play also requires you to connect your device via usb first, that's how/why they don't require root access I believe.

Another related blog post says:

> **What to do if you don’t have a USB cable from the begining?**

*If you don’t have a USB cable at first, then you need to root your
device first then run the following command on your device:*

> setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555

*Then you need to stop/restart the adb daemon:*

> stop adbd
>
> start adbd
>
> **How to switch back to USB transport mode?**
>
> adb usb

*But there is one caveat*

> This only works since Android 4.0 (ICS). If you have to develop/hack
>   on other Android versions then you need to root that device (in order
>   to use ADB in unsecure mode).

[source](http://www.chentir.com/2012/11/10/drop-that-embarrassing-usb-cable-when-you-develop-on-android/)

Comment: I had already check from that source, as I initially refered to that only, but still it gives me the same problem!

Comment: Have you looked into rooting your remote device? Did you try updating your android sdk/tools? Maybe try starting cmd.exe as administrator before executing your commands?

Comment: I don't want to root my device!